# rosout high memory usage

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosout, libroscpp, xmlrpc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running `melodic` on a ubuntu 18.04 container (through `systemd-nspawn` inside Archlinux:

```
uname -a: Linux rsl-bionic 5.3.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT @1572357769 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using only
`rosrun rosout rosout`
Uses upwards of 8.6Gb of Resident memory.
I don't have the ponts to upload the traces, also I'm not really sure what I'm doing when I am trying to trace it output.
But in one allocation 8.6Gb seems to be initialized in the `XmlRpcServer` in a

```
std::vector<pollfd, std::allocator<pollfd> > ::resize(unsigned long) in ?? (libroscpp.so)
```

Any pointers for fixing/tracing this?
I'll probably have to give up and repartition my machine and install ubuntu natively, but I can't reason as to why/how it could be related.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336963/rosout-high-memory-usage/) by [ixil](https://answers.ros.org/users/48914/ixil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-11-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the same setup and ran into the same problem but managed to fix it after creating a Debug build of the core ros libraries and analyzing the code of the `XmlRpcServer` where the massive memory allocation happens.

The `XmlRpcServer` in `ros_comm` sets up a vector for querying all possible file descriptors to check if it has run into the limit of opened files. When running a container on Arch however, this limit is 1073741816. With each file descriptor having a size of 8 Byte, thats 8GB for every ros node. You can check the current (hard) limit of the running shell with `ulimit -Hn`. If you reduce the limit with `ulimit -Hn 524288`, the memory usage should be fine again.

You can make this limit persistent by adding the file `/etc/security/limits.d/30-nofilelimit.conf` in the container with the following content:

```
#<domain>  <type>  <item>  <value>

*          soft    nofile  1024
*          hard    nofile  524288
```

---

Originally posted by [Ralino](https://answers.ros.org/users/50334/ralino/) with karma: 46 on 2019-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-20**:
This is some good detective work @Ralino.

I would strongly suggest you open an issue on [ros/ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues) about this. Please provide sufficient detail about how you found out and where the `vector` is created, and a link to this Q&A.

Seeing as the focus of development is on ROS 2 these days I cannot guarantee it will be fixed (or implemented differently), but it would be tremendously valuable to have a record of your findings on the issue tracker regardless.

**Comment by [ixil](https://answers.ros.org/users/48914/ixil/) on 2019-12-20**:
@Ralino thanks for taking the time to post your work. I gave up in the end using the container approach. But relieved to know there is a solution

**Comment by [pumaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31635/pumaking/) on 2023-03-22**:
If anyone is having trouble with setting the hard limit: check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061572/unable-to-modify-ulimit, you may also need to run `ulimit -Sn 524288`.

**Comment by [danambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/64471/danambrosio/) on 2023-03-27**:
You can also use `docker run ... --ulimit nofile=1024:524288` to set the soft and hard nofile limits.
If you want this for all containers consider adding:

```
"default-ulimits": {
    "nofile": {
        "Name": "nofile",
        "Hard": 524288,
        "Soft": 1024
    }
}
```

To your */etc/docker/daemon.json* file.